# Populate RecyclerView with Firebase Realtime Database References

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a category RecyclerView for the `HomeFragment` and I'm having a problem with setting my category and categoryImage in the `onDataChange()` function on my `addValueEventListener`. How can I do a for loop to get all of my references under my `job-category` reference? Thank you!

**Database Reference**

[image]

**Category.kt**

```
data class Category constructor(val category: String, val categoryImage: String)
```

**CategoryAdapter.kt**

```
class CategoriesAdapter(val category: ArrayList<Category>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindCategory(category[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return category.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false)
        return  ViewHolder(view)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val categoryName = itemView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.categoryNameTextView)
        val categoryImage = itemView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categoryImageView)

        fun bindCategory(category: Category) {

            categoryName?.text = category.category
            categoryImage?.setImageURI(category.categoryImage.toUri())

        }

    }

}
```

**category.xml**

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/categoryImageView"
   android:layout_width="420dp"
   android:layout_height="676dp"
   android:background="@drawable/image_rounded_top_corners"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_photo_"
   android:contentDescription="@string/category_image" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/categoryNameTextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/category_name"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:textSize="14sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryImageView" />
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
lateinit var categoriesAdapter: CategoriesAdapter

val categories = ArrayList Category ()  

val categoriesDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(REF_JOB_CATEGORIES)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        categoriesAdapter = CategoriesAdapter(categories)


val popularCategoriesRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.popularCategoriesRecyclerView)
    val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(view.context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    popularCategoriesRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    categoriesDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            categories.clear()
            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val category = Category(snap.child("category").getValue(String::class.java)!!,snap.child("categoryImage").getValue(String::class.java)!!)
                categories.add(category)
            }
            categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("HomeFragment", "LoadPost:onCancelled", error.toException())
        }
    })

        return view
    }
```

**Logcat Errors**

```
 Process: com.zwdalpha.skedaddle, PID: 19898
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Span count should be at least 1. Provided 0
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(GridLayoutManager.java:829)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.<init>(GridLayoutManager.java:86)
        at com.zwdalpha.skedaddle.Fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:74)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at com.zwdalpha.skedaddle.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt:36)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting an error regarding not having the "no-argument constructor"?

Comment: Added my logcat errors, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put this code after categories.clear()

```
for (snap in snapshot.children){
     val category = snap.getValue(Category::class.java)

//Here is Other Option To create category object without creating no-arg con
//val category = Category(snap.child("category").getValue(String::class.java)!!,snap.child("categoryImage").getValue(String::class.java)!!)
     categories.add(category)
}
```

You can make list like this

Comment: I added your code to my question. However I have a question, why would my app try to open on emulator but shut down when I add this code?

Comment: can you add what error shows in your logcat?

Comment: Yes Alex mentioned your error you have to add no-argument constructor in your Category Model Class. Or Add Default Value to your model class params this may work or you can use normal class for this

Comment: I added my logcat errors. I included your code as well, I feel like I almost have it, but I don't know what I could be missing

Comment: Oh man error itself telling you what is wrong. When you are creating layout manager provide fix span count like 2 or 3 or 4 like this. You are indirectly provided 0 there. In your code categories.count() replace with some fix number

Comment: Tried to put 3 in the span count, but the recycler view isn't showing and nothing is in the Logcat

Comment: can you please update your code in question so i can recheck code and try to find error

Comment: Added the updated code, thank you

Comment: It should work now. I didn't find anything wrong with this code.

Comment: The RecyclerView isn’t showing up on my end. Is it because I need height or something?

Comment: I think the problem is in your imageView size provided too big. Try there width match parent and height wrap content

Comment: Still isn't showing

Comment: Observe your logcate and check what going on by debugging.

Comment: Okie dokie I’ll try to figure out what’s wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. In your `onDataChange`, you'll want to loop over `snapshot.children` and then get the value of the properties you want for each of them.

Kotlin is not my strong suit, but it should be something like this:

```
categoriesDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        categories.clear()

        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) { //  loop over children
            categories.add(snapshot.child("category").getValue<String>(); //  get value
        }

        categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException()) //  never ignore errors
    }
})
```

If the `getValue<String>()` doesn't compile, you may need add the `ktx` extensions for Firebase Realtime Database to your Gradle file, or use `snapshot.child("category").getValue(String::class.java)`.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for children through a value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#kotlin+ktx_2) and on [reading a value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners).